# How do I set credentials for google speech to text without setting environment variable?

Tags: c#, .net, google-app-engine, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

There is C# example [client-libraries-usage-csharp](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-csharp) of using the lib.

And there is example how to set an evironment variable

> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"

How do I set credentials for google speech to text without setting environment variable?

Somehow like this:

var credentials = ...create(file.json);
var speech = SpeechClient.Create(credentials);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using Grpc.Auth;
```

then

```
string keyPath = "key.json";

GoogleCredential googleCredential;
using (Stream m = new FileStream(keyPath, FileMode.Open))
    googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(m);
var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
    googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
var speech = SpeechClient.Create(channel);
```

Comment: In class `SpeechClient` `public static SpeechClient Create();` lasted version. How i can put `channel`?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're running your application on a GCP service, there's no other way to obtain Service Account credentials for client libraries than to set the environmental variable.

GCP client libraries use a strategy called [Application Default Credentials (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) to find your application's credentials.

By default, the client library will use the JSON pointed to by the environmental variable. If the JSON is not found but your app is running on App Engine, Compute Engine or Kubernetes Engine, then your application will use the credentials of the default service account (for example, the App Engine default service account, if your application is running on App Engine.)

Comment: can't Channel be used for it? https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

SpeechClient.Create() does not support the parameter credentials anymore in version 2.7.0 but I found the following solution:

```
var client = new SpeechClientBuilder { JsonCredentials = "..." }.Build()
```

JsonCredentials accepts a string with the json content.